# Is the use of Neo4j's internal ID still not recommended?

Tags: neo4j

I am planning to use Neo4j for my current project (a REST API). I've read it is discouraged to use the ID of Neo4j, as the ID can be reused upon a restart for optimisations. However, these threads date a few years back up to 2012. On the official GitHub page of Neo4j, it seems they promised to resolve this issue for Neo4j 2.x (back in 2013). It is now 2016 and Neo4j is on 3.0.

So my question is: has anything changed? Is it still unsafe to expose the ID in the API? Or are we still stuck on UUIDs to guarantee uniqueness?

Comment: Can I ask why it is downvoted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neo4j internal IDs should not be used to reference nodes or relationships in an external system. These IDs are essentially offsets that point to some place in the filestore to reference a node or relationship.

As you point out, as data is deleted this empty space in the filestore can be reclaimed, meaning that internal IDs can be reclaimed.

If you are referring to a node / relationship in an external system, a common approach is to generate a UUID and store that as a property on the node (using an index so the node can be looked up efficiently).

In Neo4j 3.x there is a [user defined function in the APOC library](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_creating_data) for generating UUIDs from Cypher. For example:

```
CREATE (p:Person)
SET p.name = "Will",
    p.uuid = apoc.create.uuid()
```

Answer (score 0):

Also have a look at https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-uuid which will generate the UUIDs for you and make sure nobody can change or delete them, without the need to change your queries.

Comment: I've tried to use neo4j-uuid before with a Spring Data Neo4j and Repository interfaces setup. I ran into the issue of the uuid being null upon the creation of an entity (most likely due to ORM caching), so I had to drop it.